# Add apk menu doesn't show up in Arc Welder

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I installed Arc Welder on my Chrome 41, every time I launch the app I don't see any "add apk" menu. What's wrong with it? 
I have an ubuntu machine. 
**UPDATE**: here is a screenshot of the window [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i12qq.jpg)

Comment: Take a screenshot of the ARC Welder screen, upload it somewhere, and link to it from your question, so we can see what you are seeing. I have no problems running ARC Welder on Ubuntu 14.10, at least in Chrome.

Comment: I think this is a good candidate to file a bug against ARC Welder: http://goo.gl/megdlG  Also, please collect Javascript logs and include those in your report

Comment: See at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999573/how-to-add-crome-app-launcher-41-updated-in-to-arc-welder-or-add-apk-in-to-arc/30000066#30000066