# How To Add Chrome App Launcher 41+ updated in to ARC Welder or Add .APK in to ARC Welder

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I want to check my .APK file to test at ARC Welder i see this on this Link [this is 
   a Link i see here but did not get it](http://www.omgchrome.com/google-launch-port-android-app-to-chrome/)
   And this link Also [link](http://www.redmondpie.com/run-android-apps-in-chrome-browser-on-windows-mac-os-x-heres-how/) How can i add ARC Welder and .APK also. how to add APKin ARC Welder.
Image are here [image: image snap shoot]

I solved here it is :- iif i press Click on WebStore then i can add Crome Web store apps but Did not install or did not get ARC Welder.here is Link [Link here to add GoogleCrome web store apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/arc%20welder%20?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher).

How to find bug in app or how we found bug in side of app if bug are inside of app..

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of problem you have?

Comment: i want to install .apk file in ARC Welder How can i do it or how do i install here my apk file to test.

Comment: Have you followed [these](http://www.redmondpie.com/run-android-apps-in-chrome-browser-on-windows-mac-os-x-heres-how/) steps? In which step you encounter problem?

Comment: yes of cause where i am wrong please Tell me ....

Comment: Have you installed [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) from Chrome Web Store?

Comment: i have already declared here at posted image here  you can see

Comment: How Do i Find bug in App or How to test app are bug free or not How ARC welder Generate bugs in app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by Reinstall Full ARC Welder install Update size 112 mb after that emfinbmielocnlhgmf...crx file was automatically download and install at Crome App Launcher which is ARC Welder size of file "emfinbmielocnlhgmf...crx" 7 or 8 mb install ....
Blow Pic [image]